# Problem with openni2_camera, Primesense not detected

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, primesense, openni2-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to access the rgdb information of a Primesense sensor. I have ros-hydro-openni2-* installed using sudo apt-get and it previously worked just fine with the following command: `rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node` but now when I run this command this is what I get:

```
~device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1409576381.725333109]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni2-camera-0.1.3-0precise-20140720-0503/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
[ INFO] [1409576384.725593448]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni2-camera-0.1.3-0precise-20140720-0503/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
```

I used to be able to access the rgbd information and the topics using exactly the same command about a month ago. I dont know if there has been an update which has led to this.
I have ubuntu 12.04 and ROS hydro installed.

I get the same error whether the Primesense sensor is plugged in or not and lsusb doesnt detect this device.
I have tried setting the `UsbInterface=0` in `/etc/openni2/PS1080` as suggested in one of the posts but it didn't help.
I would really appreciate your help on this.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance!

---

**Update** 20140903

So this is the output

```
$ lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 005: ID 5986:026a Acer, Inc 
    Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1199:a001 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
    Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
    Bus 002 Device 006: ID 17ef:100f Lenovo 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

// now with the Primesense connected

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 5986:026a Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1199:a001 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 17ef:100f Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1d27:0609 ASUS 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried another USB port this time it works. I can see the topics but it gives me warnings when I try to see the images in rviz. this is what I get when I do rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node

```
[ WARN] [1409670134.768244447]: ~device_id is not set! Using first device.
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
[ INFO] [1409670134.765734383]: Device "1d27/0609@2/13" with serial number "1402170229" connected
```

and for rviz :

```
[ WARN] [1409675797.585762340]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Stream size does not match calculated image size in Image::loadRawData at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreImage.cpp (line 283)
[ERROR] [1409675797.585842146]: Error loading image: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Stream size does not match calculated image size in Image::loadRawData at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreImage.cpp (line 283)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191630/problem-with-openni2_camera,-primesense-not-detected./) by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-09-01**:
It might be that the PrimeSense sensor died, it is sad, but it happened to me before. If you have spare, try another sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your sensor doesn't appear in lsusb, it means that the OS isn't detecting it properly. This is usually a hardware problem.

You may want to try a different USB port or a different USB cable, if you can. If you're using a USB extension cable, try plugging the sensor in directly.

It may also be useful to review the kernel log ( dmesg ) to see if the device is partially detected, and is having signal integrity or other problems.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on 2014-09-02**:
Thanks a lot for your reply. I installed OpenNI2  and was able to run an example which accessed the depth information and printed them. However lsusb still does not show the Primesense sensor. I think there must be a problem with ros-hydro-openni2 or openni2_camera since it is working outside ROS.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-02**:
The lsusb database doesn't include names for some of the primesense devices. I suspect your device may be showing up in lsusb without a label. Can you add your lsusb output to your question?

**Comment by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on 2014-09-03**:
You are right. I post the what I get with and without the sensor being connected to the computer in the post below.